# Why two controllers with conversation scope cant see each other?

Tags: cdi

I have and CDI bean UserController annotated as @ConversationScope with an attribute named as user with getters and setters exposed.

```
@ConversationScoped
@Named("userController")
public class UserController implements Serializable {

    private User user;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.user = new User();
    }

    //getters and setters ommited...

}
```

I also have an second class with my Observers.

```
@ConversationScoped
public class UserObservers implements Serializable {

    @Inject private UserController controller;

    public void createObserver(@Observes @MyQualifier MyEvent event) {

        this.controller.getUser().setName("Test Name");

    }
}
```

The user property is filled in my interface and i want my observer to change the name of the user, but the user property always returns null.

Its like my observer is located in a different conversation.

Can i have more than one conversation active for the same user session?

Update:
When i change my navigation rule to redirect, the code works correctly.

Comment: can you update your question with the code that initializes the user?

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that you did not start the conversation? Then you will get a new conversation for each request. Injecting the conversation into both beans and debugging its state / id should certainly reveal the problem.

Comment: I did that. conversation.isTransient() returns false and conversation.getId() returns the exact id of my conversation.